# How to compare multiple lists to see which is the most equal

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I compare multiple lists against another list to see which is the most equal? For example, how would I compare listOne against listTwo and listThree to see which matches the values of listOne most closely? I want to match on a number of common items.

```
List<String> listOne = ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Fish", "Snake"];

List<String> listTwo = ["Cat", "Zebra"];

List<String> listThree = ["Cat", "Dog", "Lion", "Fish", "Butterfly"];
```

Comment: what are the criteria to choose a closest one? number of common items, order of the items... anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> listOne = ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Fish", "Snake"];

  List<String> listTwo = ["Cat", "Zebra"];

  List<String> listThree = ["Cat", "Dog", "Lion", "Fish", "Butterfly"];

  print(nearestList(listOne, [listTwo, listThree]));
}

class IndexedValue<T> {
  final int index;
  final T value;
  IndexedValue(this.index, this.value);
}

List<T> nearestList<T>(List<T> firstList, List<List<T>> otherLists) {
  final firstSet = firstList.toSet();
  List<IndexedValue<Set<T>>> sets = List(otherLists.length);

  for(int i=0;i<otherLists.length;i++){
    sets[i] = IndexedValue(i, otherLists[i].toSet().intersection(firstSet));
  }

  final nearest = sets.reduce((a,b) => a.value.length > b.value.length ? a : b);

  return otherLists[nearest.index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> listOne = ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Fish", "Snake"];

  List<String> listTwo = ["Cat", "Zebra"];

  List<String> listThree = ["Cat", "Dog", "Lion", "Fish", "Butterfly"];

  int listTwoCount = -1, listThreeCount = -1;

  if (listOne.length >= listTwo.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listTwo.length; i++) {
      if (listOne.contains(listTwo[i])) listTwoCount++;
    }
  }
  if (listOne.length >= listThree.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listThree.length; i++) {
      if (listOne.contains(listThree[i])) listThreeCount++;
    }
  }
  if (listTwoCount != -1 && listThreeCount != -1) {
    if (listTwoCount == listThreeCount)
      print('List 2 & 3 has same matches !');
    else if (listTwoCount > listThreeCount)
      print('List 2 has more matches');
    else
      print('List 3 has more matches');
  } else
    print('No matches found !');
```

Output:

> List 3 has more matches